# How to index all csv files in a directory with Solr?

Tags: hadoop, indexing, solr, cloudera, solrcloud

Given a directory with hundreds of tab-delimited csv files, each of which contains no header in the first row. That means we will specify the column names by other means.These files can be located on a local disk, or HDFS.

What is the most efficient way to index these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a lot of files , i think there are several methods to improve indexing speed :

First , if your data on a local disk , you can build index use multithreading , but need to pay attention to, each thread has its own index of an output directory. Finally merged them into an index so that improve search speed .

Second , if your data on HDFS , i think use Hadoop MapReduce to build index is very powerful .
in addition , some UDF plugins of  Pig or Hive  also can build index easily , but 
you need convert your data into hive table or make pig schemal , these is simple !

Third , in order to better understand above methods , maybe you can read 
  [How to make indexing faster](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveIndexingSpeed)

Comment: You can use list mark up in your answer for greater readability .